# AutoCompleteTextView Using the Google Place API is not working

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, google-places-api

I have to create an `AutoCompleteTextView` using Google Places API.I have tried the following code, but it is not working.  I  am not getting any error, and am unable to get any suggestion like Google search box.

Please suggest how to do this or where I am going wrong.

```
   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item);
   AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
   adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
   textView.setAdapter(adapter);
   textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   if (count%3 == 1) {
   adapter.clear();
  try {

        URL googlePlaces = new URL(
        // URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="+ URLEncoder.encode(s.toString(), "UTF-8") +"&types=geocode&language=fr&sensor=true&key=<getyourowndamnkey>");
        URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
        Log.d("GottaGo", URLEncoder.encode(s.toString()));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        }
        JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString());            
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("predictions"));

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                adapter.add(jo.getString("description"));
            }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }        

 }

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
  int after) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a LogCat message, like the one you have for GottaGo which includes a few expected results from the Places Api, this could help you check the data to see where the problem is at.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="+ URLEncoder.encode(s.toString(), "UTF-8") +"&types=geocode&language=fr&sensor=true&key=<getyourowndamnkey>
```

This is the link you are trying to URL Connect to. Have you actually put  in your code, or did you just place the default google one in there for this example? If so, that is why you can't download it.

Try putting the link into your browser, it should still display data, and it will tell you if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the s.toString to args[0] :)